# is there a way to assign exif array result to a string in php?

Tags: php, exif

I am having trouble in assigning a simple exif result to a variable as a string, here is the code.

```
$img ="img.jpg";

$exif = exif_read_data($img , 0, true);

$imgTags = $exif["IFD0"]["Keywords"];

$findme = "someTag";

if (strpos($imgTags,$findme) !== false) {
    echo "true";
}
```

It always throws false but if I echo the `$imgTags` variable as follows it should be result as true:

```
echo $imgTags; // prints: someTag
```

what's going on? please help!

Comment: `var_dump($imgTags)` and/or `echo urlencode($imgTags)` will show any hidden special characters.

Comment: true, var_dump($imgTags); outputs this string 'string(7) "someTag"',anyway  the stripos should be true, right?

Comment: the strpos should return a numeric value starting at 0 for the first char of the value of the position of the string you are searching for or false if it does not exist, using !== you mention stripos, & your code does not show case insensitive.... I prefer to echo var_export($var,true); for debugging